# What is the best way to make a 27element long form in Android?

Tags: android, forms

What is the best way for perfomance to make a form which has two columns the first always a textview and the second is spinner or edtittext and it has 27 lines?

i have a scrollview but the "activity_form.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance" or i should ignore this error msg?

Thank you!

edit: like this
[image]

Comment: Do you have "27 packs" of textview + spinner or edittext or you have a one textview + spinner or edittext with 27 lines of height?

Comment: Use a listview with a custom layout and create a custom adapter for it, which will also decide basing on the position getView() receives, which layout to instansiate.

Comment: as i heard the edittext not works with listview